# error raise when use within GROUP with string_agg in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, string-aggregation

My query in postgresql 10, raises an error when it uses within GROUP clause

> ERROR:  function string_agg(character varying, unknown, integer) does
>   not exist

I have tables at and atrelation. at has unique id and description while atrelation stores multiple transaction with code of related at and transaction line id. for example

product row with id 6 has a column name tag has value service5% and contco4.5%

product row with id 5 has tag  value service5%

I need to show 2-rows i.e row 6 and 5.

row 5 show the column tag value 'service5% and contco4.5% '

row 6 show the column tag value 'service5%'

```
select  atrelation.id, 
        string_agg(at.description, ' and ' ) within GROUP (ORDER BY atrelation.id )  as tag1    
from  at, atrelation    
where atrelation.id = atrelation.atid   
group by atrelation.id    
order by atrelation.id desc;
```

above query raise following error,

```
ERROR:  function string_agg(character varying, unknown, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: select atrelation.purchase_order_line_id as id, string_agg(a...
                                                        ^
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
********** Error **********

ERROR: function string_agg(character varying, unknown, integer) does not exist
SQL state: 42883
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Character: 49
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the ORDER BY into the function call and remove the `WITHIN GROUP` part:

```
string_agg(at.description, ' and ' ORDER BY atrelation.id)  as tag1
```

Comment: i did but raise ERROR:  syntax error at or near "from" 
select atrelation.id as id, string_agg(at.description, ' ANQ ' ORDER BY atrelation.id ) within GROUP

Comment: select  atrelation.id, string_agg(at.description, ' and ' ORDER BY atrelation.id  ) as tag1  within GROUP 
  from  at,  
        atrelation  
 where atrelation.id = atrelation.atid 
 group by atrelation.id  
 order by atrelation.id desc;

Comment: @aqh: you need to remove the `WITHIN GROUP` use it exactly as I have show.

Comment: thanks @a_horse_with_no_name . i guess you have to choose a good name after this good answer